# How to use Spring Data JPA Repository for update query between 2 tables?

Tags: jpa

I have 2 tables ABC and XYZ and deviceId(PK in ABC) serves as the foreign key.
How can I use spring data JPA repo methods, in a way - updateDeviceType(Which is in ABC Table), if I want to do an update query something like below,

### ABCRepository

```
@Modifying
@Query(name = "updateDeviceType", value = "UPDATE ABC abc,XYZ xyz SET abc.deviceType = ?1 WHERE abc.deviceId = xyz.deviceId.deviceId AND xyz.deviceId.deviceId= ?2")
```

The error comes like 
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found ',' near line 1, column 45

Comment: Post Device, UserDeviceMapping entity classes and the DeviceRepository. Are you using any custom query in repository for this update and when are you getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your JPQL [update query](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/structure) seems to be incorrect. As you did not post your ABC and XYZ classes, I can only quess you are going for something simillar to the following:

```
UPDATE ABC abc 
SET abc.deviceType = ?1 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM XYZ xyz 
        WHERE 
            abc.deviceId = xyz.deviceId.deviceId 
            AND xyz.deviceId.deviceId= ?2
    )
```

That is a fairly complex query and I would suggest creating a named query out of it, and not holding it in the `@Query` annotation.

Side note: You should also remember that there is an option of using native queries in JPA and Spring Data JPA if you are only going to deploy to a single type of database and it offers a nicer UPDATE syntax.